# How come a Spring application does not exist at the end of the main method

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks

I'm starting to learn Java with Spring and I've written some simple scheduled tasks.

I don't understand the mechanism that the framework uses so the application does not exit after the `getBean` call. How come the application keeps on printing "Hi"?

```java
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ...
        PeriodicTask task = appCtx.getBean(PeriodicTask.class);
    }
}
public class PeriodicTask {

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    public void periodic() {
        System.out.println("Hi");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given `@Scheduled`, I'm going to assume your `ApplicationContext` has some scheduled configuration. This means that your are creating (implicitly or explicitly) a `SchedulerExecutorService` which spawns non-daemon threads. The application will not end until all non-daemon threads have completed. One of these threads is executing your `periodic` method every 5000 milliseconds.

Now, you could put your `ApplicationContext` instantiation in a `try-with-resources`. Once execution leaves the `try` block, the `ApplicationContext` would be closed, shutting down the `ScheduledExecutorService` and eventually terminating your program.

Comment: Thanks, clear answer. One small thing, the try-with-resources won't work with ApplicationContext since it does not implement AutoCloseable, right?

Comment: @vvondra You can declare it with the actual implementation, ex. `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`.